# What am I getting wrong with my tab bar controller delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have the following class

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("It worked!")
    }
}
```

as I understand it from the documentation, the tabBar function should be called whenever a tab bar is being pressed but it isn't.

The storyboard looks as follows[image: Storyboard screenshot]

Where the class is inside the HomeScreen node on the view controller. I'm trying to do this operation here because I have a specific function call that must be made inside this class that I need to call every time a user presses it's corresponding tab controller.

Comment: What class is the delegate set to?  It should be set to the FeedViewController

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.delegate = self
```

Make your controller a delegate of itself. You can do that also in IB. Right click on tabbarcontroller view and drag delegate to itself.  Also can use this method from UITabBarControllerDelegate:
        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect        viewController: UIViewController)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding

```
tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

To the feedViewController